# Board game probability

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to compute the probability of some dice combinations for a board game and I am having some troubles. I have an approach to do it but it is lengthy and painful. I am seeking a better approach.

The game is simple, you have to roll N = 6 dices and do some combinations like:

- 1, 3, 6
- 2, 2, 5
- 1, 1, 1, 1

These combinations can be achieved by multiple rolls. At each roll you must keep AT LEAST one dice and the kept dice must be part of the combination. If you cannot keep any dice and you haven't achieved the combination your turn ends.
I would like to find an approach to compute the probabilities of such combinations.

I firstly approached the problem by computing the probability of obtaining exactly n dices over N with a value x. From that I could draw the tree diagrams and compute all the required probabilities, but the resolution gets extremely long.

Comment: Should be migrated to [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: dice = plural of die. dices = what a chef does to vegetables.

Comment: You could code a simulation and just do a million trials; that should be good enough for practical purposes.

Comment: I think this question is fine here, as it's about combinatorics. However, a few more specifics: do the numbers have to appear in the specified order? Are the three combinations you gave the only possible ones or are there others? Show us at least a little of what you've done so far.